# Incorrect After Update trigger logic

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, common-table-expression

I'm getting wrong logic in the trigger. I'm getting wrong number of records inserted into the Audit table after update on the base table. Below is the code snippet to recreate this issue.

```
create table #T1 (id int NOT NULL, CODE varchar(3) NOT NULL, pkID INT NOT NULL)
insert into #T1 (id, CODE, pkID)
values(1, 'vak', 1989),(2,'Vl2',1988), (2,'Vl2',1988)--, (null, 'Gotik')
go

create table #T2 (id int NOT NULL, CODE varchar(3) NOT NULL, pkID INT NOT NULL)
insert into #T2 (id, CODE, pkID)
values(101, 'vas', 1979),(105,'va3',1973), (4,'va5',1888),  (4,'va5',1888)--, (null, 'Popik') 
go 

create table [MyDB].dbo.Test_Dec22nd2017 (id int NOT null CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY, Ln varchar(10) null)
insert into [MyDB].dbo.Test_Dec22nd2017 (id, ln)

values (1, 'vasya1'),(2,'vasya3'), (4,'vasya2'),(5,'Super'), (6,'LYAYA'), (105,'TERSDF'), (101,'DFSDS')
go 


DROP TRIGGER DBO.TR_TEST_DEC22nd2017
GO
CREATE TRIGGER DBO.TR_TEST_DEC22nd2017
ON [dbo].[Test_Dec22nd2017] AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
    NOT FOR REPLICATION

AS 
BEGIN 

    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM 
                                inserted ins
                    FULL OUTER JOIN deleted del ON ins.ID = del.ID
                    INNER JOIN 
                    [MyDB].dbo.Test_Dec22nd2017 a ON a.id = ISNULL(ins.ID, del.ID)
                    INNER JOIN #T1 t ON t.id = a.id
                    LEFT JOIN #T2 t2 ON t2.id = a.id
                    --WHERE t.id IS NULL AND t2.id IS NULL 
                )

        BEGIN

            WITH CTE2 AS (
                    SELECT 
                        ISNULL(ins.ID, del.ID) AS ID,
                        CASE 
                            WHEN ins.ID IS NOT NULL AND del.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'UPDATE' 
                            WHEN ins.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'INSERT'
                            ELSE 'UPDATE' END
                        AS AuditType  
                    FROM inserted ins 
                    FULL OUTER JOIN deleted del 
                            ON ins.ID = del.ID
                    ) 

            ,AUDIT_CTE2 AS (    
                    SELECT DISTINCT     
                        CTE2.ID, 
                        'OVC' AS Code,
                        CTE2.AuditType
                    FROM CTE2
                    --  WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
                        )

                    INSERT [MyDB].[dbo].[AuditTable] (Code, ID, AuditType)/*, ParentCode, ParentID)*/
                    SELECT
                        Code,
                        ID, 
                        AuditType
                    FROM AUDIT_CTE2
        END 

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM 
                                inserted ins -- ISNULL(T.pkID, t2.pkID)
                    FULL OUTER JOIN deleted del ON ins.ID = del.ID
                    INNER JOIN 
                    [MyDB].dbo.Test_Dec22nd2017 a ON a.id = ISNULL(ins.ID, del.ID)
                    LEFT JOIN #T1 t ON t.id = a.id
                    LEFT JOIN #T2 t2 ON t2.id = a.id
                    WHERE t.id IS NOT NULL OR t2.id IS NOT NULL
                ) 

        BEGIN

            WITH CTE AS (
                SELECT 
                    ISNULL(ins.ID, del.ID) AS ID,
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ins.ID IS NOT NULL AND del.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'UPDATE' 
                        WHEN ins.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'INSERT'
                        ELSE 'UPDATE' END
                    AS AuditType  
                FROM inserted ins 
                FULL OUTER JOIN deleted del 
                        ON ins.ID = del.ID
                        ) 

            ,AUDIT_CTE AS ( 
                    SELECT DISTINCT     
                        CTE.ID, 
                        'TST' AS Code,
                        CTE.AuditType,
                        ISNULL(T.CODE,T2.CODE) AS ParentCode,
                        ISNULL(T.pkID, T2.pkID) AS ParentID
                    FROM CTE
                    INNER JOIN MyDB.dbo.Test_Dec22nd2017 a ON CTE.ID = a.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN #T1 T ON T.id = a.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN #T2 T2 ON T2.id = a.id 
                    WHERE T.pkID IS NOT NULL OR T2.pkID IS NOT NULL
                        )

                    INSERT [MyDB].[dbo].[AuditTable] (Code, ID, AuditType, ParentCode, ParentID)
                    SELECT
                        Code,
                        ID, 
                        AuditType,
                        ParentCode,
                        ParentID
                    FROM AUDIT_CTE
        END 
END
```

**This is what causes to insert two wrong records into the Audit talbe**

```
GO
UPDATE [MyDB].dbo.Test_Dec22nd2017
SET Ln = 'DDD' WHERE ID 
IN (101,105,11)
SELECT TOP 30 * FROM  [MyDB].[dbo].[AuditTable] ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

[image]

[image]

As you see from the pictures above it insert 5 rows into the search audit table. But should insert only 3. One for ID 6 with Parent Code = Null and ParentID = NULL and two records for ID 101 and 105 with ParentID of 1973 and 1979 and corresponding Parent Codes.

These two statements work perfectly fine.

```
insert into [MyDB].dbo.Test_Dec22nd2017 (id, ln)
values (44,'vasya1'), (45,'vasya2')
SELECT TOP 30 * FROM  [MyDB].[dbo].[AuditTable] ORDER BY 1 DESC

GO

UPDATE [MyDB].dbo.Test_Dec22nd2017
SET Ln = 'DDD' WHERE ID
IN (5,10,6)
SELECT TOP 30 * FROM  [MyDB].[dbo].[AuditTable] ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: By running your code I got 4 records inserted into the AuditTable, 2 OVC and 2 TST against 101 and 105 which is right by how you have written the trigger. Your image shows a record that's marked right with Id 6. How is that right?

Comment: Tony, For the first update statment, that causes this issue the trigger is supposed to return only 3 records as follows: 2 records with ID 105 and 101where ParentID is not null and one record with id 6 with parentID of NULL. The issue here that it also inserts records with id 105 and 101 with ParentID of NULL.

Comment: Is your question why the first 'IF NOT EXISTS...' block is getting executed that inserts OVC records?

Comment: The trigger as its written is working correctly. The OVC records of 101 and 105 is inserted because its Id's does not exist in #T1 as its checked in the `IF NOT EXISTS` block of first INSERT. How do you want it changed?

Comment: Hi Tony, the problem that the first update statement inserts records with ID 101 and 105 with ParentID = NULL, which I do not want for that first update statement. In that statement I only need records with ID 101 and 105 with parentID Not NULL as well as record with ID 6 = NULL. The second and third Update statements work fine.

Comment: So can we summarize the logic for inserting an audit record with ParentID = NULL? From what you say so far I understand that such a record should be inserted if it does not exist in #T1 or in #T2. So that it does not insert 101 or 105 but inserts 6. Is that what you want?

Comment: Correct Tony, If the record with ID 6 is not present anywhere in any of the two tables, #T1 or #T2 then I should insert the records into the Audit table such records with ParentID and ParentCode of NULL. At the same time if any of the rerecords with ID 101 and/or 105 exist in the  #T1 or #T2 table then they should be inserted into the Audit table with corresponding ParentCode and ParentID that always NOT Equal to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the first `IF NOT EXISTS` in your trigger to:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM 
                inserted ins
    FULL OUTER JOIN deleted del ON ins.ID = del.ID
    INNER JOIN 
    [tempdb].dbo.Test_Dec22nd2017 a ON a.id = ISNULL(ins.ID, del.ID)
    LEFT JOIN #T1 t ON t.id = a.id
    LEFT JOIN #T2 t2 ON t2.id = a.id
    WHERE t.id IS NULL AND t2.id IS NULL 
)
```

to ignore any ids that either exist in #T1 or #T2

Comment: Tony, this is exactly what I've tried already and that is exactly why I posted this question. This only repeats the issue. See my second picture above with row id 3 and 4. I do not want to have those two records inserted into the Audit table.

Comment: Have you tried replacing with the above? It shouldn't insert 101 or 105 with patent id = NULL. That is those two wrong rows in your second image. For me it didn't

Comment: Yes, I replaced with your code from the above and I got 5 records inserted into the Audit table exactly as it appears on the second image.